# Hide/show options of optgroup (angular material) with a click

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a list of interventions, interv1, interv2, interv3 ...
for each of these interventions, i have a list of elements, it gives this following :

```
<mat-optgroup *ngFor="let interv of listIntervDiag" [label]="interv.name" [disabled]="interv.disabled">
         <mat-option *ngFor="let element of interv.listElement" [value]="option">
                      {{ element }}
         </mat-option>
</mat-optgroup>
```

I would like to do a tree (like here https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview) but in the select element.

At the beginning I show only my OptGroup, when click on one of these group options, I want to show the list of elements related to (the options)

Is it possible to do that ?

maybe not ... I guess the solution could be to do 2 select, and according to the selection of the first select it shows differents element in the second one (which is disable if nothing is selected in the first one).

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hello @Helene, the answer given is valid and answers your question. Please, quote it as your chosen answer, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In mat-option tag

```
[class.active]="i === activeClassIndex"
```

In mat-optgroup tag

```
*ngFor = "let interv of listIntervDiag let i = index;" (click)="activeToggler(i)"
```

In .ts file

```
activeToggler(selectedIndex) {
    this.activeClassIndex = (this.activeClassIndex == selectedIndex) ? null : selectedIndex;
   }
```

in.css file

```
.mat-optgroup {
    .mat-option {
         display: none;
          &.active {
              display: flex !important;
          }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the [hide show response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55074260/7971925) to stop the list from scrolling when you select items.  Add [cdk virtual scrolling](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h4xptu-zyj4yh?file=app%2Fselect-reset-example.html)

```
  <mat-select [value]="selections | async" multiple >
    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport [itemSize]="10">
      <mat-optgroup *cdkVirtualFor="let interv of listIntervDiag"; let i = index;">
        <mat-label (click)="activeToggler(i)">{{interv.name}}</mat-label>
        <mat-option [class.active]="i === activeClassIndex"
        *ngFor="let childOption of interv.children" [value]="childOption">
          {{childOption.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-optgroup>
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
  </mat-select>
```

& css

```
cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport {
  height: 256px;
}
```